# Shortcoming of the code to generate the random coupon code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hashids

I'm trying to generate the random coupon codes using the below code. I'm using the [Hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) pip package to achieve this

Looking for the shortcoming of below code?

```
from hashids import Hashids    
hashid = Hashids(salt='UNIQUE ID', min_length=25)
print hashid.encrypt(0)   # aDnwJKQZ
print hashid.encrypt(999) # p32jAqVW
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't think Hashids has a encrypt function

Comment: 1. What are you trying to achieve? 2. What level of security do you require? Who is the attacker, what capabilities, what is to be gained by the attacker, lost by others?